# Firebase/Core require NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription in the info.plist file

Tags: ios, firebase

I added `Firebase/Core` to my project in the Podfile:

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
```

Than I added `GoogleService-Info.plist`.
It's all changes that I made.

Analytics works, because I see some activities from my devices in the **DebugView** in the **Firebase** console.

But after uploading the app to the store, I receive a letter with this text:

> Missing Info.plist key - This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

The Installation instruction for **Firebase** doesn't mention it

I want analytics for my app. How can I solve this problem?
For what reason do I need to specify the `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` key?

**Additional information**

1. I updated **xCode** in this app release.
2. My `GoogleService-Info.plist` has
       enabled **IS_GCM_ENABLED** flag.

Comment: Does your application uses CLLocationManager ?

Comment: Same here just now

Comment: I use this library: https://github.com/hyperoslo/ImagePicker.
It uses CLLocationManager

Comment: But it has long been used

Comment: btw: i did set IS_GCM_ENABLED to NO and updated the firebase, but the problem is still present

Comment: do you use also any of these? FacebookSDK, Fabric, Twitter ?

Comment: looks like FacebookSDK is using CoreLocation

Comment: Yes. I use FacebookSDK and Fabric. But it's already in the store

Comment: It's not Firebase. I try upload app without firebase/core. But problem doesn't gone.

Comment: Do you update xCode before uploading to the store?

Comment: I have a theory. It seems that Apple has updated its policy. And now we must explicitly add the key to Info.plist

Comment: May be your problem in FacebookSDK. In the sample for the SDK there is NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription key in the Info.plist:
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/master/samples/FBSDKPlacesSample/FBSDKPlacesSample/Info.plist

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169862/discussion-between---and-peter-lapisu).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like smth. in the Apple review changed...

i had to to remove all those frameworks to pass

```
# SDKs
# pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
# pod 'Fabric'
# pod 'Crashlytics'
# pod 'TwitterKit'
# pod 'Firebase/Core'
# pod 'OneSignal', '~> 2.4.1' # if you upgrade to newer, please also update to newer non-deprecated methods
```

however the app is unusable after that... the key is in one of those frameworks, or combination

(note, just removing Facebook and Firebase didnt helped)

---

Looks like it is caused by

```
# pod 'Fabric'
# pod 'Crashlytics'
```

---

Looks like a temp issue
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/101367

Comment: It happened again.  From Apple's email, they contains "While your app might not use these APIs, a purpose string is still required. You can contact the developer of the library or SDK and request they release a version of their code that doesn't contain the APIs."  So, we still have to include the string even our app doesn't use it.  And once we added, OneSignal will use it.

Comment: I ran into this as well and found that it was TwitterKit that was referencing CoreLocation for its TweetComposer feature. This is frustrating as we don't use that feature and don't need location services at all, but we're going to have to add the privacy string anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This was not an issue with the OneSignal SDK, it was an issue with Apple's review process. It looks like they've resolved the problem however, so I would recommend uploading your build again and it should work.